# Sleep Through SIGCHLD

Tags: c, sleep, sigchld, select-function

I have a C program that polls some hardware sensors once a minute, and adds the readings to a database. To ensure that the readings are taken closer to minutely (instead of minutely + overhead time), the program creates a child to do the actual work, and then sleeps for 60 seconds before creating another child.

The trouble I'm having is that the SIGCHLD from the children are interrupting the sleep(60), causing unlimited children to be created, instead of one per minute.

This is how I've been trying to do it:

```
while(1)
{

    /* Create a child to do the work */
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        /*parent continues*/
        select(0, 0, NULL, NULL, &time);
        claim_children();
        continue;
    }
    /*Now in the child*/
    process_pvs();
}
```

I've also heard that select() can be used to achieve what I'm after by doing the following:

```
struct timeval time;

time.tv_sec = 60;
time.tv_usec = 0;

select(0, 0, 0, 0, time);
```

But for some reason this only works for 1 iteration in the while loop. After that the program does not wait at all, and creates children constantly.

So how can I best have my program do this without being interrupted by sigchld?

Comment: On Linux, I'd recommend a single-threaded, simple program using timerfd.

Comment: For the `select` call, the timeout structure may be modified. I guess you are on Linux, so see the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Comment: For the problem with signals, see e.g. [`sigprocmask`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask).

Comment: @nos The `SIGCHLD` signal is ignored by default anyway.

Comment: Another note... If you read the [`sleep` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) you will see that it returns the number of seconds left if interrupted by a signal handler. In conclusion, reading manual pages is always a good idea.

Comment: @nos My sigaction(2) man page says POSIX.1-2001 allows using SIGCHLD SIG_IGN to auto-collect zombies.  But of course some systems still don't like it since POSIX.1-1990 didn't allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the child signal with

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

This will stop the interrupts, but you need to be careful that you wait for all children. Normally a loop to catch them all.

```
while(waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) > 0);
```

This only works well if you aren't making other child processes elsewhere of course.

Comment: `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` is not portable to some older systems.

Comment: Thanks Julian, that's done the job exactly right.
aschepler, this solution is only being implemented on my machine, but I'll definitely keep that advice in mind on future works.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply code around it; detect the interrupted system call, note the time, and use logic to figure out if you need to go back into a sleep and if so, for how long.